# Is it possible to play video using videoview in background?? (android)

Tags: java, android, android-videoview

Im using Videoview to show mp4 clips and when i go back (app in background) video stop.

How can i keep playing the video? can i override onpause of the VideoView?

Comment: Why would you want to play your video when your application is running in background?

Comment: cause video is playing and if the user want to todo somthing else durning like checking texts or whatever i want the video keep playing and not stopped

Comment: That would not be encouraged. Look at youtube's video player, or even your gallery's video player. Neither have such a functionality. But if you need to force such a thing, overriding `onPause()` should be your starting point of trial.

Comment: You are correct. But if you have an iphone you can keep playing by pressing on the play button if you tapping twice on home button. I know its little but strange but i think that youtube app want to force you to stay on app whather i want the user todo what he want.

I thought on try override onpause but i didn't find any doc about it

Comment: any solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

VideoView does not stop playing when the Activity that hosts it is paused. If you are experiencing this behavior it may be for a different reason.

Comment: You think maybe because i host the activity in tabhost?

Comment: I created new project with one activity that use videoview and it does stop. I think you are wrong